# image registration: obtaining overlapped region for similarity measure when transforming template across reference

Tags: image, opencv, registration

while we are registering one image to another image(of the same size),we transformed the template image to the reference image.

Assuming that the template partially overlapped onto the reference boundary area,how do we extract out the overlapped region tocompute the similarity measure...(eg with ncc or mi)

Likewise, what is the search range

any reference example or code in opencv?

thanks in advance